# What are possible solutions to implement fulltext search in Azure?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, full-text-search, azure-sql-database

Currently I am working on an MVC 2 project and we are trying to implement fulltext search. Originally we were going to take advantage of SQL Server fulltext search capabilities but we are aware that the project will be moving to Azure within 6 months.I understand that SQL Azure does not support fulltext search currently. What are the possible solutions to implement full text search in Azure? The solutions we've come across seem to point to Azure Library for Lucene.Net but I want to make sure we aren't overlooking any better solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lucene.net is the only option I am aware of as well.